# An Rspec helper like assert_database_unchanged?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec

Is there an rspec extension for postgresql that allows one to test something like this?

```rb
expect { make_bad_request }.to not_change_database
```

i.e. To ensure nothing was created, updated or deleted.

Sure, we can check a specific table but most often we just want to be sure that nothing changed at all, nothing sneaked in some multi-stage save.

It's not particularly easy to do with a little helper because although postgres has `pg_stat_database` it's not updated during the test transaction. I can still see how it's doable but it would be a bit of plumbing. Has anyone done it?

**UPDATE:**
I was asked to give an example of how this might be useful.

The convention with HTTP is that if a request returns an error status then no change has been made to the application state. Exceptions to that convention are rare and we like convention over configuration.

Active record helps with enforcing this with defaults about how validation works but it still leaves lots of ways to make mistakes, particularly with complex chains of events where it's most important to have atomicity.

As such, to enforce the HTTP convention with ease you could take it even further than as stated above and instead have something like a directive expressed as something like

```
describe 'error responses', :database_changes_disallowed do
  context 'invalid form data' do

    before do
    ...setup belongs only here
    end

    it 'returns 422' do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec is already able to use database transactions to isolate state changes on a per-example level, this would aim to subdivide just one further between the `before` and the `it`.

This will work for a well designed app if you have been judicious enough to ensure that your database stores only application state and no pseudo-logging like `User#last_active_at`. If you haven't then you'll know immediately.

It would greatly increase test case coverage against the some of the worst kind of state corruption bugs whilst needing less code and removing some testing complexity. Cases where a database change suddenly *is* made for a previously working test would be as a result of an architectural change in an unfortunate direction, a real and unusual need to make an exception or a serious bug.

I'll be sad if it turns out to be technically infeasible to implement but it doesn't seem a bad idea in terms of application design.

Comment: I would just write more specific assertions to check if the tables in question have been altered. While the looks like a good idea at first glance I think the devil here is really in the details and there is a reason why Rails does not ship with anything like it.

Comment: Any particular details in mind? The issue of "Tables in question" is one of the things under test. We must assume our controller is only affecting the tables we think it is. 
I'd guess rails doesn't ship with it because they believe in db agnosticism and some dbs would not support this. Personally, I don't believe that agnosticism is very achievable in practice so I'm happy to use DB specific add-ons.

Comment: I'm not sure agnosticism is the only concern, rather its find a reliable indicator that works inside a transaction and which does not give you false negatives/positives. Testing that your code doesn't have any unexpected side effects at all is usually not a very viable strategy. Test for the most likely side effects or known bugs.

Comment: Yes, if it's prohibitively hard to implement reliably then, yes, these fall in the realm of reasonable assumptions and are bearable.

Comment: Like always it is very hard (or even impossible) to prove that something did not happen. But easy to prove that something was done. Can you add an example of a method that you think should have a spec that proved that no record was changed in the database? And elaborate on why you think it is not enough to spec that the number of records did not change or that a specific record didn't change?

Comment: What if you're running your test suite in a parallel mode? Two different specs running at the same time may modify the database causing your `not_change_database` call to blow up. The existing matchers are more appropriate solutions.

Comment: In response to @spickermann and anothermh, these are implementation hurdles that should - in principle - be fully solvable with the sandbox that is the database transaction (it has full knowledge of whether anything changed within that bound). It's believable that it might be really tricky with common DBs though. If it's anything other than a flawless implementation, I agree it wouldn't be worth using.

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky one, because it's not easy to tell what should not happen in your app. IMO better to keep the focus of your specs on what the app should do.

In other words: if you want to test that no DB changes were made, should you check that no files were written? And no requests were made? Should you test that no files permissions have been changed?

I guess you get my point.

But, there might be a legit reasons to do it I don't know about. In such case, I'd use something like [db-query-matcher](https://github.com/civiccc/db-query-matchers)

```rb
 expect { your_code_here }.not_to make_database_queries(manipulative: true)
```

I usually used and and seen it being used for N+1 tests (when you want to specify how many times a specific query is called), but it seems this matcher would work for you as well.

But it can be very brittle: if you add such checks to most of your tests, and your app is evolving, you can have a failing specs just because some actions started to need a DB update. Your call.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah it's only worthwhile if it keeps things easier and safer rather than adding brittleness. If at some point you decide you _do_ want database mutation where you didn't before then that seems a good place for brittleness.

Your answer would work except that it's still possible to fire queries and roll them back on error. Really, in postgres the issue is the way that a transaction isn't a recursive concept but activerecord pretends it is by use of savepoints.

Comment: And yes, I do think that in the absence of the control of side-effects a functional language gives you it would be good if there were easier ways of expressing "This failure mode should create zero state change in my application". The reason not to do this seems to be purely about implementation difficulty.

Comment: Why not just assume that DB transactions work properly, and check that (whatever you're doing) is being done under a transaction?

Comment: You're most likely to ensure atomicity by wrapping your various `save!` in a transaction. When a 422 is returned from the second call, the first is rolled back, the database is left unchanged but I'm assuming this gem would say a manipulative query happened. (Or does it account for transactions?)

Comment: As for why not check that the production code has been written correctly, that's what the test is for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```rb
assert_no_changes(expressions, message = nil, &block)
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_no_changes

Comment: Unfortunately not. The subject of the block is the tricky part. It needs to know whether the database data changed.